# CPU temp is wrong?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan

sorry for bad english

My laptop is a Dell N5110 Core i5 2410m , Nvidia GT525M , 4GB Ram

http://www.rodfile.com/3mww4i31mt9p temp of CPU right now

when it goes more than 60 the fan spin and one second later temp goes to 50 C

in games temp changing every second

my laptop fan was stuck and not spin so i opened the laptop and fixed it with oil before the fan was stuck in normal i got 55 C for CPU and 53 for GPU and in games (like farcry 4 and DayZ or Metal Gear Solid GZ ) was 80C . now the fan spin very well and the normal temp is 43 C sometimes goes to 37 but in games temp is 99 C but in one sec it goes to 60 one second later it's 95 again goes to 65 then goes to 95 C . before the fan stuck when cpu was overheated (93 C) laptop was shut down but now whet temp goes to 95 it's work just fine and the laptop and the air coming out from fan is not hot

by the way when the fan was stuck i update my bios from A03 to A11 and updated my windows (8.1) to fix the fan but fan didn't fixed . maybe overheat is for updating bios ? PLEASE HELP ME
[image: SpeedFan Screen Shot]

Comment: You say you fixed the fan (im assuming cpu fan?).  How did you fix it ?  Did you replace it with an identical fan of identical rpm?

Comment: no . i oiled the fan (with kitchen oil) and is spin good . in speedfan shows the fan speed on 5500 RPM

Comment: i'm so sorry . i can't upload image here because site says : You need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Answer (score 3):

Cooking oil is a very wrong choice, also you might have damaged temp sensor. Change the fan to a comletely new one and do not forget to apply thermal paste.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU fan might be spinning, but a spinning fan is useless unless it has good thermal contact with the CPU.  Otherwise it might be as helpful as a spinning fan on your desk (outside the laptop).

- If you removed the fan to repair it then reattach it **properly**. That is with the right thermal paste or a good thermal pad.
- If you did not remove the fan then still check it it has a proper contact with the CPU.

Also, cooking oil is not a good solution to repair with. It might temporarily help, but it is no long lasting solution.  On a positive note: It probably did not damage the temperature sensor which is often located beneath or inside the CPU.

Comment: Just to clarify, the fan shouldn't be on the CPU, the heatsink should be.

Comment: Aye. Heat sink on the CPU and on the GPU. (Or at least a heat pipe to the heat sink) and a fan on the heat sink.

Comment: But why the laptop is cool and not hot ? because before i fixed the fan laptop was very hot ?

Comment: The laptop might produce less heat if it can not get rid of the that due the thermal throtling. Can you check the CPU freq while you are gaming?

Comment: In games laptop using full Cpu speed 2.9 Ghz somethimes less like 2.5 or 2.3 Ghz

Comment: Now cpu temp is 37 ! i never seen the CPU having temp under 45